# Dumping firmware from Winbond W25Q64JVSSIQ using BusPirate

Tags: firmware, hardware, firmware-analysis

I have a Winbond W25Q64JVSSIQ flash chip that supports SPI. I've connected BusPirate through a SOP8 cable to the memory chip. `PWR` and `VREG` LEDs are on, so they're connected. BusPirate is connected to a Kali Linux VM on my host. I'm using the command, `sudo ./flashrom -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/ttyUSB0` to identify the chip, but `flashrom` isn't able to.

```
root@malnet:/opt/flashrom# sudo ./flashrom -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/ttyUSB0
flashrom v1.1-rc1-121-g8962267 on Linux 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 (x86_64)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at https://flashrom.org

Using clock_gettime for delay loops (clk_id: 1, resolution: 1ns).
Bus Pirate firmware 6.1 and older does not support SPI speeds above 2 MHz. Limiting speed to 2 MHz.
It is recommended to upgrade to firmware 6.2 or newer.
No EEPROM/flash device found.
Note: flashrom can never write if the flash chip isn't found automatically.
```

How do I get the firmware dumped from the chip? Any ideas as to why `flashrom` may not be working or alternate methods to dump?

Comment: have you tried flashrom's support options?

Comment: No, where can I find them?

Comment: https://flashrom.org/ -> Ctrl-F support